# Why did I get an error from this python code?

Tags: python

I have a question on this code im trying to write. It says an error with *"NameError: name 'answer' is not defined on line 1"*. Can someone point out what is wrong?

```
def main():

  answer = input("Would you like to play a game? yes or no")

if (answer == "yes"):

  firstChoice = input(

    "There was once a knight, stuck in a forest trying to look for a princess. The knight had 2 ways he could go. Should he go left, or right?"

  )

if (answer == "left"):

  secondChoice = input(

    "He decides to go left. As he passes the trees, he sees something he hasn’t seen before. A GIANT DRAGON! He pulls out one of his weapons. Which weapon did he pull out? Oversized Sword or Flamethrower?"

  )

if (answer == "mighty sword"):

  thirdChoice = input("He pulls out his mighty weapon. It was about as tall as a bus! The dragon said, Wait, just the size of a bus? I’m like, 200 buses. The knight, realizing that his choice was stupid, got the heck out of there! The dragon, being the 200 buses that he is, couldn’t find the puny mortal. He decided to brush it off and went to his dome. The poor knight, out of breath, gets a drink of water from a creek. The knight says, Wait, I know this creek! This is the Golden Creek, so if I follow this path, the dome should be right there! The knight decides to go with his gut and follow the path. And before he knows it, the princess was trapped inside of the dragon’s dome! He knew he had to do something, but what? Should he sneak in, or barge in alone?")

if (answer == "sneak in"):

  print("He tries to sneak in. Getting past every dragon guard, was surprisingly easy. Their eyes are on the side of their head, so if you just walk in front of them, you should be good.  Luckily, when the knight came, the dragon was asleep. He needed crucial silence, where not the single creek of wood, or cling of the armor could wake up the dragon. The knight whispers to the princess, I have come to save you! The princess carefully follows the brave knight, and they make it out! The king is happy with your success in keeping the princess alive, and you are promoted to secretary, the highest rank below the king! YOU WIN")
```

Comment: Make sure your indentation is correct.  Indentation matters in Python.

Comment: Understanding main: https://realpython.com/python-main-function/

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't need to use the parenthesis in the `if` statements. The error is likely caused by not using a tab when you define the function.
Sorry about suggesting an IDE, don't know how you could have copy and pasted the text...

Answer (score 2):

This is a scope error. You initalize answer in your main method, however as soon as that method closes, the variable is deleted. The 3 if statements do not have access to this variable.

Comment: Actually the code was not formatted at first. Someone edited to make it for readable and it was impossible to understand the code. The editor chose to make it like this, but if statements might be in function as well. Can't be sure unless the OP edits own code.

Comment: Yeah that's what probably happened, but I just gave an answer for the exact code that was submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Without running your code, i can see a big problem, you may want to try this

After each input tag, you say "if answer =="
But remember, the answer variable is going to be the first thing the user inputted

so if they put "yes" the answer variable will always be "yes" throughout the entire script unless you redefine it

EDIT
When i first answered, the post was not entirely in the code block so i couldn't see the indentation

Answer (score 0):

The variable `answer` is only within `main()` to use it outside of `main()` you should define it globally, meaning before the main function

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you just need to use `global` before the declaration.